# Writing statements in words

Tags: predicate-logic

I have to write out what the following statements mean and whether they are true or false:

1. $(∃y ∈ N)(∀x ∈ N)(x < y)$
2. $(∀y ∈ N)(∃x ∈ N)(x < y)$
3. $(∀x ∈ N)(∀y ∈ N)(x < y)$

So for number 1, would I say that there exists $y \in N$ that is greater than all values of $x \in N$ ? Would this be going in the right direction? How would I know if this is true or not?

Comment: You're right about the first one, but, in english, it's a bit more natural to say: there exists a natural number greater than all natural numbers. With this rephrasing, its trutfulness (or lack thereof) should become apparent.

Comment: Ok thanks. So for 2) There exists a natural number less than all natural numbers. Would this be the wrong way round? What would I do for 3 since both statements are the same? All natural numbers are less than all natural numbers!?

Comment: Your translation of 3. is correct: all natural numbers are smaller than every natural number. You got 2. wrong. It starts with $\forall$, yet you're starting your translation with 'there exists'.

Comment: Right I thought that would be going about it the wrong way. So all natural numbers are greater than some natural numbers?

Comment: That's right.${}$ **Edit:** please consider writing an answer yourself so the question doesn't come up as unanswered.

Comment: Will do. So only the first statement is true?

Comment: The statement *only 1. is true* is false.

Comment: So all statements are false?

Comment: All statements are false.